# PowerShell csv character replacement

Tags: windows, csv, powershell, replace

I manage to generate a csv through PowerShell script on collecting a group of server disk info, but the result output on the csv file require some data massage.

below will be the script for ref:

```
foreach($pc in $comp)
$diskvalue += Get-WmiObject @Params | Select @{l='drives';e='DeviceID'}, @{l='server',e='SystemName'}, @{Name=”size(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1mb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1mb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1mb)}}
    $diskvalue | Export-Csv C:\disk_info\DiskReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output csv file on "drives" column will contain:

> C:

Yet I would like to remove the ":" at the back that data output.

> C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
@{l='drives';e='DeviceID'}
```

to

```
@{l='drives';e={"$($_.DeviceID)".Trim(": ")}
```

`Trim(": ")` will remove any whitespace and `:` characters from the `DeviceID` string

Comment: one more question, the result "UsedSpace" contain decimal value, can i remove it or round up to whole number?

Comment: Change `"{0:N2}"` in the expression to `"{0:N0}"` (the integer after `N` is the *precision specifier*). < .5 will round down, >= .5 will round up

Comment: one more issue, i notice the csv file "UsedSpace" result contain "," between numbers, is there any method to remove those?  thanks:D